# Installing Samsung Firmware on Different Region Device

Tags: samsung, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I'd like to install Samsung Edge S7 firmware for Rogers (SM-G935W8) onto an ATT (SM-G935A) device.

I've read conflicting posts on whether or not this is, in fact, possible. My attempts at this so far haven't been successful, so I'm lead to believe not, but before throwing in the towel thought I'd confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canadian variant, SM-G935W8, uses an Exynos SoC, and has a lightly locked-down (?) bootloader; the AT&T one, SM-G935A, uses a Snapdragon SoC, and is heavily locked down, to the point 3rd-party development on it is near nonexistent.

Unless someone manages to work around the lockdown *and* port the Exynos firmware to fit the Snapdragon hardware, I'd say it's straight up impossible.

Comment: Interrogative: by attempting to flash a W8 firmware, what are you trying to achieve here? Root? Debloat? More LTE bands?

Comment: Volte WiFi support..